# Form container no sliding out?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 0 clue why my form container is not sliding out, it just doesn't move, it slides in fine, but sliding out it just doesn't work. I've tried sliding out the phoneInput itself but it just gets stuck at the end of the container. Assuming you connected everything correctly you'll notice my elements slide in, but when i click the button my intention is for them to slide out but only the heading slides out, the form container doesn't slide out, it doesn't even move.

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams();

// remove number formatting then add +1
function formatPhoneNumber(phoneNumberString) {
  var cleaned = ('' + phoneNumberString).replace(/\D/g, '');
  var match = cleaned.match(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/);
  if (match) {
    return '+1' + match[1] + match[2] + match[3];
  }
  return null;
}

// login and send input data to server
function login() {

  const input = document.getElementById('phoneInput')
  let number = input.value

  if (isNaN(parseInt(number)) || parseInt(number) === null) {
    console.log('Invalid phone number');
    const divText = document.getElementsByClassName('heading-text')[0];

    divText.innerText = 'Invalid phone number!';
    divText.style.color = 'red';
    setTimeout(() => {
      divText.style.color = "black";
      divText.innerText = 'Please enter a valid phone number! No dashes or spaces!';
    }, 3000);
    return
  } else {
    formattedNumber = formatPhoneNumber(number)
    if (formattedNumber === null || formattedNumber.length > 12) {
      console.log('Invalid phone number');
      const divText = document.getElementsByClassName('heading-text')[0];

      divText.innerText = 'Invalid phone number!';
      divText.style.color = 'red';
      setTimeout(() => {
        divText.style.color = "black";
        divText.innerText = 'Please enter a valid phone number! No dashes or spaces!';
      }, 3000);
    } else {

      let heading = document.getElementsByClassName('heading')[0];
      let phoneForm = document.getElementsByClassName('form-container')[0];


      heading.classList.add('slide-out');
      phoneForm.classList.add('slide-out');


      params.delete("number")
      params.append('number', formattedNumber)
      fetch('http://localhost:3000/login', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: params
        })

        .then(function(response) {
          return response.json()
        })
    }
  }



}
```

```css
body,
html {
  padding: 0%;
  margin: 0%;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.heading {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 2em;
  height: 60%;
  width: 100%;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  animation: slide-in 0.5s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: slide-in 0.5s forwards;
}

.slide-out {
  transform: translateX(100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  animation: slide-out 0.5s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: slide-out 0.5s forwards;
}

.heading-title {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.heading-text {
  text-align: center;
}

.form-container {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 1.5em;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  animation: slide-in 0.5s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: slide-in 0.5s forwards;
}

#phoneForm {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;
  gap: 1rem;
}

#phoneInput {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  width: 50%;
  border: solid 2px #d9d9d9;
  border-radius: 3px;
  align-self: center;
  padding: 7px;
  height: 100%;
}

#phoneLabel {
  padding-inline-start: 10em;
  font-weight: bold;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.form-submit {
  align-self: center;
  background-color: #90E0EF;
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 0.4em;
  padding: 1em 0em 1em 0em;
  width: 24em;
}

svg {
  color: #90E0EF;
}

#phoneInput:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: black;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 820px) {
  #phoneInput {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 100px) and (max-width: 595px) {
  #phoneForm {
    width: 75%;
  }
}

@keyframes slide-in {
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-in {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}

@keyframes slide-out {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-out {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}
```

````html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/login.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="heading">
    <div class="heading-image"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-shield-lock-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path  fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 0c-.69 0-1.843.265-2.928.56-1.11.3-2.229.655-2.887.87a1.54 1.54 0 0 0-1.044 1.262c-.596 4.477.787 7.795 2.465 9.99a11.777 11.777 0 0 0 2.517 2.453c.386.273.744.482 1.048.625.28.132.581.24.829.24s.548-.108.829-.24a7.159 7.159 0 0 0 1.048-.625 11.775 11.775 0 0 0 2.517-2.453c1.678-2.195 3.061-5.513 2.465-9.99a1.541 1.541 0 0 0-1.044-1.263 62.467 62.467 0 0 0-2.887-.87C9.843.266 8.69 0 8 0zm0 5a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 .5 2.915l.385 1.99a.5.5 0 0 1-.491.595h-.788a.5.5 0 0 1-.49-.595l.384-1.99A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 8 5z"/>
          </svg></div>
    <div class="heading-title">Sign In To PrivDono</div>
    <div class="heading-text">Please confirm your phone number. No dashes.</div>
  </div>


  <div class="form-container">
    <form onsubmit="return false" id="phoneForm">
      <input type="tel" id="phoneInput" name="phone" required>
      <button onclick="login()" class="form-submit">NEXT</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <script src="/js/login.js" defer></script>

</body>

</html>








```
````

Comment: You sure it doesn't work? i just opened your Snippet and after i got a working number (hell, just disable validation while testing) the logo floated right outside of the window. You sure you haven't disabled anything or some bogus Case?

Comment: @Dxg125 only the heading/logo slides. The form container where you see the input box and the button do not slide.

Comment: Ahh, good, then just add !important at the end of the attributes of .slide-out and it'll work. for example: 
.slide-out {
    transform: translateX(100%)!important;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%)!important;
    animation: slide-out 0.5s forwards!important;
    -webkit-animation: slide-out 0.5s forwards!important;
}

Comment: @Dxg125 unfourtentky this does not work, when i add !important like you just said, the animation completely breaks and both elements simply disappear with no sliding.

Comment: Yea, check the fiddle here, i just tried and overwrite it, since it didn't work rightaway, i did the same here: https://jsfiddle.net/xd6he1tv/ but without !important

Comment: class `form-container` translateX = -100% and class `slide-out` = 100%. That adds up to zero. When you add class `slide-out` you likely need to remove class `form-container`.